# Objective C - Using insertString for an NSMutable string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

With a NSMutableString, how would I insert a "-" sign at the index "0" for an NSMutableString called "a". Right now my code looks like this:

```
a = [insertString: @"-" atIndex: 0];
```

Xcode throws an error saying that 'insertString' is undeclared. Something looks very wrong with my code. Please give me guidance.

Comment: To expand on what @jop said, its `[receiver message (possibly arguments here, arguments are indicated by a : colon)]`. In this case, the correct format is `[a /*receiver*/ insertString: /*message*/ @"-" atIndex: 0 */arguments*/]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put the object inside the brackets:

```
[a insertString: @"-" atIndex: 0];
```